# Calculate the cumulative sum of the first 1000 factorials?

Tags: python, function, sum

I have asked a similar question before but this is varied a little. The following is my workout. The answer I am getting doesn't tally with the answer I get by using the python's built - in function. Please advice what I am doing wrong, I believe the built-in function's answer has got to be correct.

My workout:

```
def fact_cum(n):
    f = 1
    for x in range(1, n +1):
        f *= x
    print f

fact_cum(1000)
```

---

Python's built-in function:

```
import math
def cumFact(): 
    x = sum(math.factorial(f) for f in range(1000))
    print x

cumFact()
```

Comment: fix formatting of your code

Comment: Well, you have your solution. And you have a correct solution. It wouldn't be that difficult to compare.

Comment: I don't see you summing anything

Answer (score 4):

Your factorial function never returns anything. Change that `print` to a `return`:

```
def fact(n):
    f = 1

    for x in range(1, n +1):
        f *= x

    return f
```

Now you can sum it up:

```
sum(fact(n) for n in range(1, 1000 + 1))
```

Since you're using Python 2, use `xrange` instead of `range`. `range` creates a list in-memory while `xrange` just creates an iterator.

Comment: As a side note, you could do this much more efficiently.  Why completely recalculate `100!` when you just calculated `99!` and `100!` is simply `100*99!` :)

Comment: @mgilson: This may even be what the professor was hoping they'd realize (assuming this is homework).

Answer (score 0):

First, there's the major problem that everyone's been pointing out: You're not actually summing the factorials, or even returning a value that you could pass to `sum`, you're just printing out the factorial.

But even once you solve that, you're not actually going to be calculating `sum(math.factorial(i) for i in range(1000))`, but `sum(math.factorial(i) for i in range(1, 1001))`. If you want the former, you need to start with 0!, not 1!.

As mgilson pointed out, you don't need to start over again with each factorial. The whole point of doing a cumulative factorial is that you can accumulate the factorial and the sum in lockstep, so you only need to generate each factorial once:

```
import itertools

def factorials():
    fact = 1
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        yield fact
        fact *= i

def cum_factorials():
    cum = 0
    for fact in factorials():
        cum += fact
        yield cum

def cum_factorial(n):
    cf = cum_factorials()
    consume(cf, 1000)
    return next(cf)
```

(This requires the `consume` function from the [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), or imported from [`more-itertools`](http://packages.python.org/more-itertools/api.html)… or it should be obvious how to write it yourself.)

---

Obviously you don't need to do this by generating an infinite list of cumulative factorials and picking out the nth one, but it will stop Haskell programmers from laughing at your choice of language, and isn't that what really matters?

More seriously, imagine how you would do this on paper. First, you'd write down a list of factorials:

```
1
1 * 1 = 1
1 * 2 = 2
2 * 3 = 6
6 * 4 = 24
...
```

Then, you'd write another column alongside, summing up the factorials up to that point.

```
1             1
1 * 1 = 1     1 + 1 = 2
1 * 2 = 2     2 + 2 = 4
2 * 3 = 6     4 + 6 = 10
6 * 4 = 24    10 + 24 = 34
24 * 5 = 120  34 + 120 = 154
...           ...
```

So, how do you do the same thing in Python?

Well, one option is to reorganize the algorithm down into something you can write sequentially, something like this:

```
def cum_fact(n):
    cumulative_sum = 1
    latest_factorial = 1
    for i in range(1, n):
        latest_factorial *= i
        cumulative_sum += latest_factorial
    return cumulative_sum
```

But that's actually harder to understand than what you did on paper, and easier to get wrong.

The alternative is to figure out how to get Python to do what you did on paper: Take an infinite sequence `(1, 2, 3, 4, …)`, apply a simple transformation `*=` iteratively to that sequence to get a new one `(1, 1, 2, 6, 24, …)`, then apply another simple transformation `+=` iteratively to that to get a new one `(1, 2, 4, 10, 34, …)`. And then, you just want the 1001st value in that sequence, so… throw away the first 1000 and take the next one.

`itertools.count(1)` gives you that first sequence `(1, 2, 3, …)`. You can write it like this:

```
def count(n):
    while True:
        yield n
        n += 1
```

That's a generator function. I don't think I can explain the whole concept in a paragraph, but here's the basic idea: Instead of returning a value, it yields a sequence of values. Every time it hits the `yield`, the caller gets a value. Every time you ask for the next value, it picks up right where it left over and goes until the next `yield`. If you play with the idea for a while in the interactive interpreter, maybe it'll snap into place—but, better, you probably want to google for tutorials.

Next, while you could apply each transformation using a folding function, that's probably a bit too advanced to contemplate at this point, so I wrote them out explicitly using two more generator functions.

Finally, the `consume` itself is a bit different—it isn't a generator, but a function that takes and modifies a iterator, like this:

```
def consume(iter, n):
    for i in range(n):
        next(iter)
```

So, if have `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, …]`, and you `consume` the first 3 elements, you get `[4, 5, 6, …]`.

Comment: I understand that the answers are all already given above. But I am very new to python and a lot of the given commands are not even taught thus I believe I should attempt a more basic manner of answering. For example never imported itertools nor math. (math was a trial attempt by reading around). No idea what yield is too. But yes, will read these up and understand, need to know sooner or later anyway :)

Comment: @KeshK: I'm guessing your professor would give you an F for this if you couldn't explain it… but if you _could_ explain it, that would be a different story. And it's actually not that complicated. Let me see if I can get the idea across.

Comment: No way I'm going to blindly copy these without understanding, and yes I do not understand as of now. Still figuring it out. Appreciate any help. :)

Comment: @KeshK: Really, I just wrote it this way for fun. It is a more natural way to solve the problem once you know how to think in terms of iterators, but I don't expect you to understand it well enough to do it yourself at this point. Still, if you're willing to try, I've written something up.